# IIS no muestra errores de PHP

Tags: php, iis

Tengo una web que trabaja con IIS y PHP pero a la hora de mostrar errores de codigo, solo muestra error 500 pero no el error especifico, decir que he modificado el PHP.ini y he puesto display_errors = On pero tras reiniciar sigue sin mostrarme los errores.

¿Qué más puedo hacer para que los muestre?

Comment: El servidor ISS debería tener uno o varios archivos de log, sería cuestión de mirarlos y ver si te da alguna indicación mas

Comment: Puedes [habilitar mostrar los errores](https://mid.as/kb/00211/how-to-enable-detailed-iis-errors), pero también puedes usar el log de errores PHP. La ruta se puede ver en IIS Manager -> (Seleccionar el Server, o el Sitio) -> PHP Manager -> Error log. Por defecto está usualmente en `C:\Windows\Temp`